# SQL Server - What is the internal query of selecting columns on a view

Tags: sql-server, performance, view

If I select some columns on a view, internally SQL Server will select first all columns of the table/tables and then will make a subquery?

For example:

The View named THEVIEW could be:

```
Select id, LTrim(RTrim(Name)) as Name, Age, Age-1 as AgeMinus1 
From Persons
```

Then I will query the view:

```
Select id, AgeMinus1
From THEVIEW
```

The internal query is this:

```
Select id, Age-1 as AgeMinus1 
From Persons
```

or this (and then show me only id, AgeMinus1:

```
Select id, LTrim(RTrim(Name)) as Name, Age, Age-1 as AgeMinus1 
From Persons
```

Thanks everyone!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to view the internal workings of SQL, you need to use SQL server profiler, it's very straight forward to trace a query, suggest you use username filters or similar or you'll get overwhelmed with the amount of data.

Here's a [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/start-sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-2017) on how to run it, if you query your view you'll see the corresponding query that is generated by SQL.

Comment: I tried it but SQL Profiler shows you the query to the view... Thanks anyway